# Angular2 modal popup positioning left

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

Am using [This modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal) in angular2 and i would like to position the modal popup to the left this is what ive tried

```
<modal #categoriesmodal [cssClass]="modalchecklist">
  <modal-header [show-close]="true">
    <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
  </modal-header>
  <modal-body>
    Hello World!
  </modal-body>
  <modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
</modal>
```

On the css class

```
.modalchecklist{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
 left:0
```

}

Ive tried adding `//background color:red`  on the css class but this fails and adds the css to the background document not on the modal

Where am i going wrong on the css classes

Ive checked also on the chrome developer tools but they too dont solve the issue.

What could be wrong

Comment: Did you try without the brackets? like this: `<modal cssClass="modal-xl"`

Comment: It still fails, ive tried with class instead of cssClass but now the modal is positioned at the left corner not the right corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply a style attribute in Angular2 you can use the `[style]` directive, like this

```
<what-ever [style.backgroundColor]="'red'">I am red</what-ever>
```

To apply a class, use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html):

```
<what-ever [ngClass]="'first'"><what-ever>
<what-ever [ngClass]="['first', 'second']"></what-ever>
<what-ever [ngClass]="{'first':true, 'second':conditionExp}"><what-ever>
```

See the `ngClass` link above for multiple syntax options and using expressions.

Please note all these methods are directives and, being directly bound to the scope, they expect **expressions**. In order to pass strings, you need to qualify your expression as string: use *single-quote*s inside *double-quote*s, and they'll be correctly evaluated as strings.